# rackspace smtp for ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, smtp, actionmailer, rackspace

I want to use rackspace smtp with my rails app (redmine) but if I try to add it normally it doesn't work.

```
production:
  delivery_method: :smtp
  smtp_settings:
    enable_starttls_auto: true
    address: "secure.emailsrvr.com"
    port: '465'
    authentication: :plain
    user_name: "motbro@rubyonrails.org"
    password: "YDXOzZ"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that I need to force the tls mode and use `login` type of authentication:

```
production:
  delivery_method: :smtp
  smtp_settings:
    tls: true
    address: "secure.emailsrvr.com"
    port: '465'
    authentication: :login
    user_name: "motbro@rubyonrails.org"
    password: "YDXOzZ"
```